jspdf is showing extra padding top on element . How to fix this?
This is before creating pdf
enter image description here
this is after creating pdf, you can see that extra padding top is coming after creating the pdf in table, every element is getting extra padding.
enter image description here
How to fix this? I am using html2canva and jspdf
